# How to use override method in generic class in JAVA

Tags: java, generics, overriding, equals

I don't want to damage to polymorphism by generic. But my short thought compels casting. When i didn't do that, the eclipse regarded a equals method as of Object Class. Anyone has good solution?? The Problem is in if statement of ArraySet Class. Good luck.

```
public class Star {

    (...)

     // Public Method
     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object anObject) { (...) }

}

public class ArraySet<E> {

    // Instance Variables
    private E[] _elements;
    (...)

    // Constructors
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArraySet() {
        this._size = 0;
        this._maxSize = ArraySet.DEFAULT_MAX_SIZE;
        this._elements = (E[])new Object[this._maxSize];
    }

    (...)

    **if(((Star)this._elements[i]).equals(anElement))**

    (...)
}

public class AppController {

    // Instance Variables
    private AppView _appView;
    private ArraySet<Star> _starCollector;

    // Constructor
    public AppController() {
        this._appView = new AppView();
        this._starCollector = new ArraySet<Star>();
    }
    (...)
}
```

postscript: I'm studying English. So thanks for your pointing out.

Comment: You don't need the cast. The method that is called will be `equals(Object)` and if your `_elements[i]` is a `Star` it will be `Star.equals(Object)` that is called. Instead of trusting what Eclipse can tell about the code (it can't tell much), you should test your code and you'll see it works just fine.

Comment: Thank you Kayaman too. Have a good day~!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to damage to polymorphism by generic.

You are *not* damaging polymorphism. Casting will break the whole point of using generics.

Here:

```
 if(((Star)this._elements[i]).equals(anElement))
```

you don't need to cast `this._elements[i]` to `Star`. Just call `equals` directly on `this._elements[i]`:

```
 if(this._elements[i].equals(anElement))
```

> the eclipse regarded a equals method as of Object Class

No it does not. When you do `this._elements[i].equals(anElement)`, at runtime, the type of `this._elements[i]` will be figured out and it will call the `equals` method on whatever type it is, instead of `Object`. Basically, your `Star`'s `equals` method will be called even if you don't cast it.

Comment: @JoonheeJeong If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: I did it. This is my first question. Thank you so much!